# Minimum weight spanning tree for Directed graph with parallel edges

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I would like to have the name of algorithms can be used to find Minimum weight spanning tree from a Directed cyclic graph with parallel edges. Information on any c++ libraries that can be used to obtain the same with their analysis on runtime and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as minimum spanning tree for directed graphs. You probably have in mind minimum spanning aborescence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)).

For finding min cost aborescence there's an algorithm called Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) It can find the aborescne of minimum cost in O(VE) or O(E log V) or O(E + V log V) depending on implementation.

Comment: Minimum spanning aborescence ( computer science ) is an alias for minimum spanning tree for directed graphs (graph theory). Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm doesn't support directed parallel edges.

Comment: Well you can just modify graph so it works. i.e. theres edge u -> v with weight w1 and edge u - >v with weight w2. you just replace them with edge u -> v with weight min(w1,w2)

Comment: Good insight but I was expecting exactly two edges from u => v with weight w1 and another edge v =>u with weight w2. This weight indicates the strength of the signal between two wireless devices. In this particular scenario, it's also possible that u can connect to v ( u => v ) but the vice verse is not possible. (Hence the problem)

Comment: So in other words you have a directed graph with possible cycles u->v->u, so why Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm wouldn't work on that?

Comment: Oh, does it works with cyclic graphs?; because one of my professors told me it won't work with graphs with possible cycles. Wikipedia says   "In graph theory, an arborescence is a directed graph in which, for a vertex, u called the root and any other vertex v, there is exactly one directed path from u to v. "

Comment: Yes aborescence does not have cycles, but that's what you need right? Chu–Liu/Edmonds' takes a directed graph and finds min cost arborescence. And it works with cyclic graphs.